# Hibernate query: new DTO clause not working

Tags: java, hibernate, dto

**User Entity**

```
class User{
int id;
@OneToMany
Set<Role> roles;
}
```

:User class have so many other details which i have not written.

**DTO**

```
class DTO{
int id;
Set<Role> roles;
DTO(int id, Set<Role> roles){
  this.id = id;
  this.roles= roles;
 }
}
```

**Query**

```
hibernateTemplate.find("select new DTO(u.id, r ) from "+User.class.getName()+ " u inner join u.roles as r");
```

**Issue** : throws not a valid constructor found.

**With below constructor modification the above query works:**

```
DTO(int id, Role role){
      this.id = id;
     }
```

**Issue**: But now it gives multiple DTO records for same user equal to no of roles that user is having. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need multiple rows to create a single DTO instance, you can't use the new operator inside the query. Instead, you'll have to create your DTOs by yourself. Something like this should do:

```
Map<Long, DTO> dtosById = new LinkedHashMap<Long, DTO>();
List<Object[]> rows = hibernateTemplate.find("select u.id, r from User u inner join u.roles as r");
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    Long id = (Long) row[0];
    Role role = (Role) row[1];
    DTO dto = dtosById.get(id);
    if (dto == null) {
        dto = new DTO(id);
        dtosById.put(id, dto);
    }
    dto.addRole(role);
}
List<DTO> dtos = new ArrayList<DTO>(dtosById.values());
```

Comment: This works. But i thought hibernate was there to make lives easier. Hibernate fails miserably to expose OO layer by hiding relational behavior from developer. It leaks leaks and leaks at every place. I could only understand this by looking at the relations behavior -how the db query is working: select u.id, r.name from user u, roles r where r.user_id = u.id; This is the result what hibernate is returning.

Comment: Do the same with JDBC, and you'll realize that Hibernate does makes lives easier. It leaks, and IMHO, it's a good thing, because if you forget that there is a relational database and SQL queries behind Hibernate, you'll make huge mistakes and the performance will be abysmal. IMHO, using Hibernate without understanding what happens, precisely, behind the scene, can only lead to a performance disaster.

Comment: But, by the amount hibernate has made things easy for me, it has given pain in equal amount.

Comment: @SanjeevKumarDangi,  totally agree. With the hard learning curve and still these kinds of issues, I would probably stick with JdbcTemplate with its boilerplate code

Answer (score 0):

If you want things to be easier, you are going to love [Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) which I created for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

The entity views for your example could look like this

```
@EntityView(User.class)
interface UserDto {
  @IdMapping Integer getId();
  List<RoleDto> getRoles();
}
@EntityView(Role.class)
interface RoleDto {
  @IdMapping Integer getId();
  String getName();
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
List<UserDto> dtos = entityViewManager.applySetting(
  EntityViewSetting.create(UserDto.class),
  criteriaBuilderFactory.create(em, User.class)
).getResultList();
```